# Storing and calling specific class methods in/from an array

Tags: java, swing

I've been reading and googling for hours on how I can call

```
public class Fee {
    int id;
    String name;
    double amount;
    FeeCategory feeCategory; // miscellaneous, other, tuition, etc
    GradeLevel gradeLevel;
    SchoolYear schoolYear;
    String description;
    boolean isActive;

    public boolean isIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }



    public FeeCategory getFeeCategory() {
        return feeCategory;
    }

    public void setFeeCategory(FeeCategory feeCategory) {
        this.feeCategory = feeCategory;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public GradeLevel getGradeLevel() {
        return gradeLevel;
    }

    public void setGradeLevel(GradeLevel gradeLevel) {
        this.gradeLevel = gradeLevel;
    }

    public SchoolYear getSchoolYear() {
        return schoolYear;
    }

    public void setSchoolYear(SchoolYear schoolYear) {
        this.schoolYear = schoolYear;
    }
```

I have a number of different `getter` methods along with its `setter` methods.

I need to be able to call the method to fill the cells of a `JTable` with specific values returned by corresponding `getter` method.

So what I did was create a `DefaultTableCellRenderer`

```
public class JTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int col)
    {
        Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);

        if(row%2 == 0){
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        else{
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }


        for(int i=0; i<table.getRowCount(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<table.getColumnCount(); j++){
                if(table.getValueAt(i, j) instanceof Fee){
                    Fee fee = (Fee)table.getValueAt(i, j);
                    table.setValue(fee.getId(),i,j);
                }
            }
        }
        return cellComponent;
    }
}
```

The problem is with the for loop which I plan to use to set specific values for certain cells.

[image]

As you can see, it filled all the cells with just the `id` because I can't think of a way to iterate through `getId(),getName(),getAmount(),getDescription()`.

Is it possible to put all 4 methods in an array maybe something like

```
Methods[] myMethods = {getId(),getName(),getAmount(),getDescription()};
```

then,

```
for(int i=0; i<table.getRowCount(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<table.getColumnCount(); j++){
        if(table.getValueAt(i, j) instanceof Fee){
            Fee fee = (Fee)table.getValueAt(i, j);
            table.setValue(fee.myMethod[j],i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call just the 4 `getter` methods but not all of them.

Any solution or suggestion?

Comment: You can use your j-loop to decide, which getter you have to use. You can switch on j and if j==0 getId(), j==1 getName() and so on.

Comment: Or you could write a getter in Fee, which has as argument the column-ID, so you decide there, which value has to be returned.

Comment: 1) a switch the use a getXXX based on the column, 2) Java Stream permit you to use method reference (don't now much unfortunatly), might be able to use an array of those (Something like `Fee::getId`),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need some sort of switching logic to handle the mapping of index to getter method. For me, the neatest way is to use Java 8 lambda functions, something like the example below. As you can see, this adds a getValue(int index) method to the Fee class which does what you want. The mapping is handled by a Map created in the static initialisation.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Fee {
    private String name;
    private int fee;

    private static Map<Integer, Function<Fee, Object>> getterIndex = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        getterIndex.put(0, Fee::getName);
        getterIndex.put(1, Fee::getFee);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Fee setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public int getFee() {
        return fee;
    }

    public Fee setFee(int fee) {
        this.fee = fee;
        return this;
    }

    public Object getValue(int index) {
        return getterIndex.get(index).apply(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fee fee = new Fee().setName("Barry").setFee(1000);
        System.out.println("name: " + fee.getValue(0));
        System.out.println("fee : " + fee.getValue(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would do that Map (or array) in the GUI since the order and getter wanted will depends on the JTable you want. But I was hoping to see this answer!

Comment: Agreed - refactoring the logic to map index to method into the display logic would be a better overall design. The code example is more to show the technique as simply as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In order to dynamically call methods like that, you'll need to use reflection and possibly introspection.

Reflection is when you programmatically use the structures of your program itself, such as `Class` instances, the methods they define. If you take a look at the [Java `Class` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), you'll find it has methods for accessing its constructors, fields, methods and more.

Introspection is the ability to use properties of some object at run-time. Classes that conform to the JavaBeans specification allow introspection, which offers some abstraction that's easier to use than pure reflection. The [`Introspector` class in package java.beans](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) allows you to obtain bean info for a class. From there, the "properties" of that class can be used. A property could be a field with a getter and/or setter, or a getter/setter not backed by a field (that may simply operate on logic). It allows for more than that, such as registering a listener with a property on an instance so that if the property is changed through a setter, the listener is called. This is useful for a model-view-controller approach, where changes to some instance may require update events being fired on the view. For example, if some part of your code changes properties of objects that are represented as rows in your table, outside of the GUI, the listener could be used to update the corresponding cell.

If you want to use an array, you'll have to populate it with [`Method` instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html). These would be the read methods (and possibly a separate array with write methods) for the corresponding PropertyDescriptors you get via the introspection. Such a `Method` can then be invoked on an object, provided the access rules allow it. It might actually be better to use a Map, which maps names to the `Method`, so the actual order doesn't matter. This would make it easier to refactor your user interface later. You may also want some way of mapping the actual column names to the property names, but if you set specific rules regarding naming and stick to them, you could derive the property names from the column names, or reverse things and show a column for each property automatically.

EDIT: Maybe interesting to know why you need to do these things in such a round-about way. Java does not have first class methods. This means that methods cannot be passed around as arguments or treated as any other piece of data, the way you could in JavaScript or Scala. So reflection is needed to obtain and invoke methods indirectly. Java 8 introduced some functional programming concepts with lambdas, but they are a form of single-method interface in disguise. Furthermore, Java is not a dynamic language such as Ruby or Python, it is a statically compiled language. So some things that are simple (but also easy to break) in other languages require reflection in Java. If you come from a non-Java background, the way you need to do some things may feel cumbersome.

Comment: There is other solution that would prevent the usage of Reflection (kind of the last solution to use). A simple Builder to generate the row for the `Fee` class. Or like the other answer said, Java 8 provide a new solution to reference a method

Comment: @AxelH I lack experience with Java 8 and didn't know it had that convenient double colon operator. That makes BarrySW19's answer the better approach if Java 8 is used, since it brings things much closer to approaching methods as first-class.

Comment: @gh don't worry, I am not better with it either ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add to Fee class:

```
    public Object myMethod(int j) {
switch (j) {

    case 0:

        return this.getId();

    case 1:

        return this.getName();

    case 2:

        return this.getAmount();

    case 3:
        return this.getDescription();
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

You should have a list of Fee records:

```
 List<Fee> feeData=new ArrayList<Fee>();
```

Then call:

```
                    for(int i=0; i<feeData.size(); i++){
                            if(feeData.get(i) instanceof Fee){
                                for(int j=0; j<table.getColumnCount(); j++){
                                Fee fee = (Fee)feeData.get(i);
                                table.setValueAt(fee.myMethod(j),i,j);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```